# Mongo Client always fails with error 'Attempt to add global initializer failed, status: DuplicateKey S2RegionCovererInit Aborted (core dumped)'

Tags: mongodb

I've seen posts with similar errors people have had because they didn't have the correct C++ driver. I'm not developing in C++. I'm seeing these errors thrown from the Mongo Client while simply trying to run 'mongo' or 'mongo --version'.

I'm using Mongo for a laravel application that is crashing with the message: Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Connection refused

The application was running fine until this morning when I ran a simple mongodump command to backup the database.

Comment: what is your OS and Mongo version? This looks more likely to be an OS issue

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10, I can't tell which version of Mongo I'm using. I'm assuming 2.x based on other environments I've seen.

Comment: Seeing this on a Jenkins box. Apparently stopped right away the same time you reported this. Super odd.